# Background Music Restarting

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am programming a game which switches between SKScenes. When I start playing the background music from the start screen, switch to a new screen and back to the start screen the music starts playing again.
I can't find out how to run the music once and not restarting again and again. I could make a workaround with storing a bool in NSUserDefaults to check if the music is running but that seems like an awful workaround. There must be a more simple solution. I have attempted with `static` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new empty swift file and add this code into it:

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
var musicOnPlayScene = Bool()

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {

        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
        if (url == nil) {
            print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
            return
        }

        var error: NSError? = nil
        do {
            backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            backgroundMusicPlayer = nil
        }
        if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
            print("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()

}
```

Now play your background music into start scene this way:

```
playBackgroundMusic("yourSong.mp3")
```

and when you switch a scene add this code into next scene's `didMoveToView`:

```
backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
```

This will resume your background music when you switch any scene.

Hope it will help.